How to create database using custom role with superuser using just terminal and make it live in localhost?
I am facing a problem while creating database. I created a superuser named "rahi007". Then using pgadmin4 I can easily create database and table and make it accessible through localhost. But when it comes to do the above thing, I can't do this with ubuntu terminal. I need "rahi007" to be the owner of the database. I need a proper solution.
I tried looking for solutions but couldn't find. I expect to get solution on how to create database with this user "rahi007" and make it live with localhost.

Why not? You haven't given us any details I'm afraid. There is nothing you can do with pgadmin that you can't do with psql.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html
you can use CREATE DATABASE sales OWNER  rahi007;

@RichardHuxton I want specific commands for the whole setup. Can you help me with that?

The documentation reference by @mshabou is the whole setup. Read it, try it. If you have further issues then ask another question showing what you tried and the issue.
